# How to say "the time is..."

Tags: traducción

Is there a Spanish translation for saying "the time is....". I know most of the time, people just say, it is 2:30PM or something, but is there a direct translation from English?

Comment: You say that most of the time people just say "it's 2:30PM" or something like that. So in what contexts do people say (or can you hear) "the time is 2:30PM"?

Comment: @charlie that construction is most common in English in transportation where time is often announced over a loudspeaker.

Comment: @Charlie the speaking clock (a telephone service) always used to say At the third stroke the time will be ....

Comment: @mdewey even for that kind of services I would just say "al tercer tono serán las...", omitting the "time" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option can be simply: *La hora es*

My grandmother had a radio that said aloud the time by pressing a button. With a robotic voice, it was like:

> La hora es: 21 horas 20 minutos.

You can infer this translation from the translation of the question when we want to know what time it is:

> What time is it? -> *¿Qué hora es?*

and with that:

> the time is -> *la hora es*

But as you and others have commented, the usual answer would be:

> It's 9:30 a.m -> *Son las 9:30 a.m / Las 9:30 a.m*

Comment: And if you want it to sound more officious, I suppose you could say, "La hora oficial es ..." or "La hora de Greenwich is ..."